# Can I access headers in http channel inbound adapter status code expression?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I have an HTTP inbound channel adapter so configured:

```xml
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="/api/requests"
    channel="httpRequestsChannel"
    path="/requests"
    supported-methods="POST,OPTIONS">
    <int-http:cross-origin allow-credentials="false" allowed-headers="*" origin="*" />
</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I'd like to make it reply 201 to `POST` requests and 200 to others (i.e. `OPTIONS`), but none of:

- `headers.get('http_requestMethod').equals(&quot;POST&quot;) ? 201 : 200`
- `:headers[http_requestMethod].equals(&quot;POST&quot;) ? 201 : 200`
- `&quot;POST&quot;.equals(:headers['http_requestMethod']) ? 201 : 200`

for the `status-code-expression` attribute worked, most of them end in a failed context initialization with:

```
IllegalStateException: No node
```

Am I using the wrong syntax here or those details aren't available at that stage?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24147573/3127111) where a gateway is suggested, but I'd like to stick with the adapter for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expression doesn't get access to the `requestMessage`. However it really may make sense. Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter.

As a fix for your problem I would suggest to configure it like this expression:

```
status-code-expression="T(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder).requestAttributes.request.method.equals('POST') ? 201 : 200"
```